# Windows Script to Find String in Log File

Tags: string, find

I have IBM Cognos TM1 application running as Services on Windows Server 2008. When I start the Service, TM1 will write a log file named "tm1server.log" on "D:\TM1\log\". TM1 will continously write this log until the service is ready, which normally takes 3 hours until the service is ready. When the service is ready, TM1 will write "TM1 Server is ready" on the log.

I want to make a script that continously check the log file until the string "TM1 Server is ready" is written. When the string found, I want the script to run another script that will send email to me. I have made the script for sending email.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks and regards,

Kris

--edit--

i use findstr command to search the string:

findstr /d:d:\TM1\log\ "TM1 Server is ready" "D:\TM1\log\tm1server.log" >> result.log

but the result.log contains all of the contents of tm1server.log.

Comment: Please post in your code over here so others able to understand the problem and provide answer.

Answer (score 0):

On my server, 'TM1 server is ready' is written each time the server starts. So I have many 'TM1 server is ready's in one file.

You could test the last returned 'TM1 server is ready' to see when it happened to see if it happened in the last 5 (or whatever) hours with something like:

```
PS E:\TM1_Server_Logs> (Get-Date(select-string .\tm1server.log -pattern '(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*TM1 server is ready' | select -expand Matches | foreach {$_.groups["timestamp"].value} | Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" | Select-Object -last 1)).AddHours(-5) -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-5)
```

That's a long one-liner, but it should work. If it returns true you could decide what to to next.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```sh
findstr /C:"your token to find" "C:\targetFile.log"
```